# how to use properties file in J2ME?

Tags: ant, java-me, globalization, j2mepolish, build.xml

I am not able to build my application via Ant build.xml file when I am using Properties file in my app. Can anyone tell me how to use properties file in j2me?
eg ApplicationConfig.properties file

Comment: could you please specify the problem? Post specific parts of the build.xml, and clarify the problem as exactly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this post in nokia forum](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?156540-Read-Config-Properties-XML-File-in-J2ME), .properties files are not supported in J2ME.